# Adding a Nanostation M5 to a Juniper network.

Tags: juniper

Alright, so I got tasked by one of my professors to try and connect a Nanostation M5 to the current network of the faculty. I was instructed to connect it to a Juniper WLC800 controller.

Now, I'm a newbie at these sort of things (which is why I chose a networking course), so I don't really know where to even start. I asked some of the assistants for help, but they are reluctant to try in fear of messing up the network somehow.

So far, most of what I've found and read on the internet is documentations. I haven't been able to find whether Juniper controllers are compatible with Ubiquiti devices, nor have I been able to find someone else doing this. Everyone I've talked to about this is skeptical that you can even do it.

So, are Juniper controllers compatible with other devices / Nanostation M5? Is it safe to try it without breaking the network? Has someone else attempted this and I just couldn't find it?

And well, pardon if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Re: "I got tasked by one of my professors to try and connect a Nanostation M5 to the current network of the faculty": please ask your professor.   The question doesn't look on topic, since the Nanostation is a consumer AP, and this isn't a network that you have control over

Comment: @user5025 Nanostation M5's are _Customer Premises 
Equipment_; which isn't really the same as 'consumer AP'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are Juniper controllers compatible with other devices / Nanostation M5?

No controlling the AP from a WLC requires [CAPWAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPWAP) however the Nanostation doesn't support it... the [Unifi series uses TR 069](http://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi/UniFi-questions-moved-from-FAQ-thread/td-p/111384), but the Nanostation is a autonomous unit that won't coordinate with anything else (thank you jona)

Comment: Bummer, but thank you kindly for your answer. At least now I won't have to hit my head off a wall.

Comment: A note on the Ubiquiti gear. The linked article is for UniFi APs, not Nanostations. Nanostations are stand-alone devices and don't work with a controller. The UniFi management protocol isn't TR-069. The linked article says that it's TR-069 *like* but it isn't the same.

Comment: Thank you. Main point is that they don't use capwap either